# Creating a matplotlib 3D surface plot from lists

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

i want to create a surface plot of the lists shown in the code. It's a simplification of data i'll import from an excel file once i figured out how to plot it.

x and y should represent the plane from which the z-values emerge. I created a random matrix to pair up with the 3x10 values from x,y.

This is the error Message:

> ValueError: shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


x = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10] #creating random data
y = [0,1,2,3]
a = np.random.rand (3, 10)

z = np.array(a, ndmin=2) #not really sure if this piece is necessary. 


fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1, projection='3d')

x, y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
ax.plot_surface(x, y, z)
plt.show()
```

> ValueError: shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape

I've already tried to leave `z = np.array(a, ndmin=2)` out. Didn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is two-fold:

- First, you have 4x11 points and not 3x10 points
- Second, you need to import `Axes3D` for enabling the 3d plotting. You don't need to use additionally `z = np.array(a, ndmin=2)` I think

---

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

x = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10] #creating random data
y = [0,1,2,3]
a = np.random.rand(4, 11)
x, y = np.meshgrid(x, y)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1, projection='3d')

ax.plot_surface(x, y, a)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: i'm such a massive retard. Would you mind if i delete the problem and rob you of your well deserved reputation?

Comment: @AlexanderK it's too late - the answer has a positive score so you [won't be able to delete it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/141367/284827).